# retain in Objective C

Tags: iphone

for eg.

```
NSMutableString * str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initwithString:@"matrix"]; 
NSMutableString * str2 = [str1 retain]; // str2 = matrix - output
NSMutableString  * str3 = [str1 copy]; //str3 = matrix - output
```

what happen when 2nd line execute. are str1 and str2 different objects ? str1 points to "matrix", but is str2 also points to "matrix" ? if i change contents of str1, will str2 content changed ??

Comment: You can't change the contents of an NSString. It's immutable.

Answer (score 40):

`str1` and `str2` are *pointers* that reference the same area of memory. Your memory layout looks roughly like this:
[image]

If you change where `str1` points, e.g., by doing this

```
str1 = @"new string";
```

then `str2` will still reference "matrix", but `str1` will reference "new string":
[image]

Let's say, though, that `str1` and `str2` actually pointed to an instance of an `NSMutableString`, and you did this instead:

```
[str2 setString:@"new string"];
```

Note, then, that `str1` and `str2` would still point the same object, so by modifying `str2`, `str1` would also change to "new string".

### Shallow copy vs. deep copy

A *shallow copy* is a copy of an object in which its instance variables still point to the same memory location as the original object's ivars. A *deep copy* is a copy in which copies of the instance variables are also made.

Let's say you have a class, `MyClass`, that has two instance variables, each of type `NSString`. Here's a diagram of what the memory layout would roughly look like after a shallow and a deep copy:

[image]

Comment: what is a difference between shallow copy and deep copy in objective c ?

Comment: Probably worth a separate question, but I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: What'd you use to make the diagrams?

Comment: Colin Barrett: It looks like OmniGraffle. I recognize the shapes from its templates.

Comment: @Colin Barrett: Yeah, it was a quick diagram made with OmniGraffle.

Comment: g8 explanation ! Thats what i am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> what happen when 2nd line execute. are str1 and str2 different objects ?

No. They point to the same object, which now has a `retain` count of 2. (`init` increments this counter)

> str1 points to "matrix", but is str2 also points to "matrix" ?

Yes.

> if i change contents of str1, will str2 content changed ??

Yes.

Comment: And str3 will not change when you change str1 or 2, although NSString is immutable.  As a style note, for clarity, if you retain on str2, you should usually later release str2 or whatever you give control of str2 to.

Comment: can you tell me when we write [str1 copy], is it perform shallow copy or deep copy ?? If shallow then how can we perform deep copy, what is an exact difference between them ?

Comment: The distinction between shallow and deep copies is for container objects like `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, not for `NSString`.